# How do I grant write access to an app pool?

Tags: iis-8.5

I am trying to depoly a .net core 2.0 webapi on IIS
The [help here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#common-errors) states

"Only use the stdout log to troubleshoot app startup failures. Never use stdout logging for routine app logging. There's no limit on log file size or the number of log files created. The app pool must have write access to the location where the logs are written. All of the folders on the path to the log location must exist. For more information on the stdout log, see Log creation and redirection. For information on logging in an ASP.NET Core app, see the Logging topic."

I visited the [log creation and redirection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.1#log-creation-and-redirection) link and I still can't figure out how to do this.

I expect that I need to use windows explorer to go to the logs folder and grant a permission, but what is the user name I grant the permission to?

I see from [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) that an application pool name can be used for an identity but when I try entering it as an object name to add a permission it can not be found

[image]

Looking at the application pool advanced settings I see the Identity is ApplicationPoolIdentity however that also is not found if I enter it as the object name

The Built In ApplicationPoolIdentity is not listed 
[image]

Comment: investigating https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: Usually that means the "application pool identity" in IIS configuration.